# Using a dictionary for a quiz?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I need to create a quiz that gives the user a state and they have to give me the capital city. But for some reason when I run it it's not deleting used cities like I want.

Code

```
import random
def main():
    capitals={"Washington":"Olympia","Oregon":"Salem",\
                    "California":"Sacramento","Ohio":"Columbus",\
                    "Nebraska":"Lincoln","Colorado":"Denver",\
                    "Michigan":"Lansing","Massachusetts":"Boston",\
                    "Florida":"Tallahassee","Texas":"Austin",\
                    "Oklahoma":"Oklahoma City","Hawaii":"Honolulu",\
                    "Alaska":"Juneau","Utah":"Salt Lake City",\
                    "New Mexico":"Santa Fe","North Dakota":"Bismarck",\
                    "South Dakota":"Pierre","West Virginia":"Charleston",\
                    "Virginia":"Richmond","New Jersey":"Trenton",\
                    "Minnesota":"Saint Paul","Illinois":"Springfield",\
                    "Indiana":"Indianapolis","Kentucky":"Frankfort",\
                    "Tennessee":"Nashville","Georgia":"Atlanta",\
                    "Alabama":"Montgomery","Mississippi":"Jackson",\
                    "North Carolina":"Raleigh","South Carolina":"Columbia",\
                    "Maine":"Augusta","Vermont":"Montpelier",\
                    "New Hampshire":"Concord","Connecticut":"Hartford",\
                    "Rhode Island":"Providence","Wyoming":"Cheyenne",\
                    "Montana":"Helena","Kansas":"Topeka",\
                    "Iowa":"Des Moines","Pennsylvania":"Harrisburg",\
                    "Maryland":"Annapolis","Missouri":"Jefferson City",\
                    "Arizona":"Phoenix","Nevada":"Carson City",\
                    "New York":"Albany","Wisconsin":"Madison",\
                    "Delaware":"Dover","Idaho":"Boise",\
                    "Arkansas":"Little Rock","Louisiana":"Baton Rouge"}

    wrong=[]

    print ("STATE TEST \n")


    while len(capitals)>0:
        pick=random.choice(list(capitals.keys()))
        correct_answer=capitals.get(pick)
        print ("What is the capital city of",pick,"?")
        answer=input("Your answer: ")
        if answer.lower()==correct_answer.lower():
            print ("That's Correct!\n")
            del capitals[pick]
        else:
            print ("That's Incorrect.")
            print ("The correct answer is",correct_answer)
            wrong.append(pick)

    print ("You missed",len(wrong),"states.\n")


    if incorrect_answers:
        print ("Here are the ones that you may want to brush up on:\n")
        for each in wrong:
            print (each)
    else:
        print ("Perfect!")
main()
```

Comment: Define "not deleting used cities like I want".

Comment: When the user guesses incorrectly, you don't remove the state from the dict, and the user can guess again later. Is that what you want? Also, where is `incorrect_answers` defined?

Comment: What evidence do you have that it's not deleting the correctly answered picks?  Are you seeing repeated picks?  Try reducing the initial `dict` to just 1 or 2 entries to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Are you saying that  del capitals[pick] isn't working in the success if->then? I notice you don't have that same code in the fail if->then, so you should definitely add that in.

Comment: The values are removed from the dictionary for me. Once the dictionary is empty there is an error - `incorrect_answers` is not defined.

Comment: You don't need the backslashes for line continuation between `()`, `[]`, or `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing the state from the dict only when the answer is correct, you need to remove it unconditionally, try with this code:

```
import random
def main():
    capitals={"Washington":"Olympia","Oregon":"Salem",\
                    "California":"Sacramento","Ohio":"Columbus",\
                    "Nebraska":"Lincoln","Colorado":"Denver",\
                    "Michigan":"Lansing","Massachusetts":"Boston",\
                    "Florida":"Tallahassee","Texas":"Austin",\
                    "Oklahoma":"Oklahoma City","Hawaii":"Honolulu",\
                    "Alaska":"Juneau","Utah":"Salt Lake City",\
                    "New Mexico":"Santa Fe","North Dakota":"Bismarck",\
                    "South Dakota":"Pierre","West Virginia":"Charleston",\
                    "Virginia":"Richmond","New Jersey":"Trenton",\
                    "Minnesota":"Saint Paul","Illinois":"Springfield",\
                    "Indiana":"Indianapolis","Kentucky":"Frankfort",\
                    "Tennessee":"Nashville","Georgia":"Atlanta",\
                    "Alabama":"Montgomery","Mississippi":"Jackson",\
                    "North Carolina":"Raleigh","South Carolina":"Columbia",\
                    "Maine":"Augusta","Vermont":"Montpelier",\
                    "New Hampshire":"Concord","Connecticut":"Hartford",\
                    "Rhode Island":"Providence","Wyoming":"Cheyenne",\
                    "Montana":"Helena","Kansas":"Topeka",\
                    "Iowa":"Des Moines","Pennsylvania":"Harrisburg",\
                    "Maryland":"Annapolis","Missouri":"Jefferson City",\
                    "Arizona":"Phoenix","Nevada":"Carson City",\
                    "New York":"Albany","Wisconsin":"Madison",\
                    "Delaware":"Dover","Idaho":"Boise",\
                    "Arkansas":"Little Rock","Louisiana":"Baton Rouge"}

    wrong=[]

    print ("STATE TEST \n")

    incorrect_answers = False

    while len(capitals)>0:
        pick=random.choice(list(capitals.keys()))
        correct_answer=capitals.get(pick)
        print ("What is the capital city of",pick,"?")
        answer=raw_input("Your answer: ")
        if answer.lower()==correct_answer.lower():
            print ("That's Correct!\n")
        else:
            print ("That's Incorrect.")
            print ("The correct answer is",correct_answer)
            wrong.append(pick)
            incorrect_answers = True
    del capitals[pick]

    print ("You missed",len(wrong),"states.\n")


    if incorrect_answers:
        print ("Here are the ones that you may want to brush up on:\n")
        for each in wrong:
            print (each)
    else:
        print ("Perfect!")
main()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is quite possibly intentional behaviour - if you get it wrong it goes back into the question pool. It isn't clear from the question what the desired behaviour is.

Comment: The whole point of the question is that it isn't deleting used cities as he wants, it looks clear enough